# a for loop in r with matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I am new to R and I have been all over stackoverflow and I couldn't find answer to my simple question.

I have a list of matrices, A,B,C... of dimension m x m and a single vector, V of dimension m x 1
I want to first multiply matrix 'A' by X, and use the resulting vector to multiply the next matrix in the list, I want something like this

```
m1 = A x V
m2 = B x m1
m3 = C x m2
...
```

I have 89 matrices to go through, manual is not an option, as I need to update number of matrices a number of times, is there a simple for loop kind of technique to make my life simpler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's solution where you loop through all the matrices and store multiplication result in `resultMatrix` list.

*m1 = A x V* step is done with `origMatrix[[i]] %*% myVector` where *i = 1*
*m2 = B x m1* step (and all the rest) is done with `origMatrix[[i]] %*% resultMatrix[[i - 1]]`

```
# Generate data
origMatrix <- list(matrix(rnorm(9), 3),
                   matrix(rnorm(9), 3),
                   matrix(rnorm(9), 3))

myVector <- 1:3

# Loop trough original matrices    
resultMatrix <- list()
for (i in 1:length(origMatrix)) {
    if (i == 1) {
        # Multiple first matrix by vector
        resultMatrix[[i]] <- origMatrix[[i]] %*% myVector 
    } else {
        # Multiple matrix by previous result matrix
        resultMatrix[[i]] <- origMatrix[[i]] %*% resultMatrix[[i - 1]]
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, you made my day.

Comment: Right now I am putting the matrices in the list origMatrix manually after they are created as list = (t89,t88,...,t1). Is there a way of doing this automatically, the order they appear in the list also matters.

Comment: @user8889655 something like this will work, but please check order of your matrices! `for(i in 89:1) {origMatrix[[i]] <- get(paste0("t", i))}`